# re render a react component only when the state change

Tags: reactjs

hi am new to react and Firebase and i want to understand why  this component keep re rendering .
basically what i want to do is getting the data and display it and keep listening for changes and update the data without reloading the page

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from '../util/firebase';

export default function Items() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    let data = [];
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('items')
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
        console.log(changes);
        changes.forEach((change) => {
          data.push(change.doc.data());
        });
        console.log(data);
      });
    setItems(data);
  }, [items]);
  return <div>{items && items.map((item) => <h1>{item.text}</h1>)}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Remove items from effect dependency and do setItems directly after console logging data.

Comment: i did that but this way when i add new item the component dosent render again to show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) re-runs the function passed to it when one of the dependencies change.

If we analyse the current `useEffect` function, you can see that it sets a state for `items` using `setItems` which will cause a re-render. But the dependency also contains `items`.

Component mounts -> `useEffect` -> sets item -> `useEffect` detects change in items, reruns -> sets item again, continues.

Since you do not actually use `items` inside the `useEffect`, you can safely remove it from the dependency array.

Another hazard here is that the `useSnapshot` function is async, so when compiler gets to `setItems`, it will not have run the `useSnapshot` yet and hence data will be empty. To get around this, you can move the `setItems` function inside:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
  let data = [];
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("items")
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
      console.log(changes);
      changes.forEach((change) => {
        data.push(change.doc.data());
      });
// spreading the data here did solve my problem
      setItems([...data]);
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: this way when i add an item the component will not re render to display the new data how i can fix that ?

Comment: @SalahEddinBerriani you could extract contents of `useEffect` into a function of it's down and call the same function after you add an item

Comment: @Agney You are mutating data so when you set state you keep setting it to the same reference, try the following: `setItems([...data]); `

Comment: @Agney @HMR spreading the data like this `setItems([...data])` did make it work thanks both for the help :)